# JDBC driver connection failed

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jdbc, database-connection

I am trying to connect java to MySQL.when i try to connect,it shows the error message:[image]

But i don't know where the error is.I am using windows 7.Netbeans 6.5.1.please help.
and when i click on start:
[image]

and this opens:
[image]

what to set in this??

**UPDATE:**

Its strange that Derby is getting connected:

[image]
[image]

and i din't provide any username and password.

Comment: Do you have MySql installed on your system?

Comment: "But i don't know where the error is" - the error message seems pretty clear. It's trying to log into the local mysql instance using a username of root and a password of YES. It sounds like that's not a valid combination in your system...

Comment: @PauliusMatulionis thats for sure.I am able to run query

Comment: @JonSkeet how to solve this?

Comment: Well, give a username and password which *does* work. We don't know what *should* work on your system...

Comment: is your password are right ?  make sure the caps letters in  password may be the issue @joey rohan

Comment: Well if you've set up MySql and the server is running then credentials must be wrong.

Comment: If your username and password are correct and the server is running, then you have likely not granted the necessary permissions to that user for the schema you're accessing.

Comment: @codeghost when i installed MySQl,i kept sesame and root as password and username.

Comment: @PauliusMatulionis Please look at the updated question

Comment: @ATR yeah,tried 50 times.no use.

Comment: [Refer Here](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html)

Comment: `thats for sure.I am able to run query`. If are able to run the query that means you have connected somehow.

Comment: I would suggest to recreate the connection in netbeans and test it first, before clicking finish. There is a button to test the connection. If the connection is successful, then you won't have problems like this.

Comment: @PauliusMatulionis run query in sql commandline,not on netbeans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download heidisql from follwing link 
http://heidisql.googlecode.com/files/HeidiSQL_7.0_Setup.exe
and try to connect to your mysql using heidisql. If its success then use the same properties(username,password etc) in netbeans too...

Comment: WOW!!! that was wonder.I don't know how to thank you.It's a great tool!my username and password were different and i don't know that why your tool was showing passowrd (blank) as i set it as sesame while instaling sql.And also it showed me some different username.not local host.I don't know how.I made these changes and Poof!! worked!!
THANKS!!!:)) hugs.

Comment: It was BLANK ! but i dont know how its possible?? god daam! forget and forgive!

Comment: @joeyrohan -You're welcome. I know heidisql is a great tool. Thats why i suggested it to you. In case of any future problems just contact me.. Have a nice day..

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying 'Access denied for user', so it means that the username/password you provided are not correct.

Comment: but when i installed MySql,i kept same user name and password which i am using

Comment: when you installed MySQL you specified a password for root. In netbeans did you specify the same password?

Comment: it can't be the error is clearly saying Access denied which means invalid username or password, or the user doesn't have access to that specific database.

Comment: yup.but i swear, i kept same un and psw,n that to installed 4 times.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you did something wrong with the configuration. Recreate the connection and test it before clicking `Finish`.

I've just tried to do this with my local MySql and Netbeans:

[image]

The connection was successful. If you can't succeed the connection at this point, then check if the database exists, and check your username and password you are providing for the connection.

Comment: I dont get that test connection thing